# Difference between System.Data.SQLite and sqlite-net-pcl

Tags: xamarin, sqlite, xamarin.android, system.data.sqlite, sqlite-net

I am just curious about this, given that I've already read [Xamarin's Documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/working-with/databases/) regarding Local Databases.

is it that `sqlite-net-pcl` is designed for use with `XAMARIN`?. I mean, if they both run `SQLite` Database Engine, then, would it be safe to assume that i can use `System.Data.SQLite` NuGet Package if I wanted to too?

`SQLITE-NET-PCL NuGet Package`

[image]

`SYSTEM.DATA.SQLITE NuGet Package`

[image]

Would it cause harm? Or it is really, and only recommended to use this `sqlite-net-pcl` plugin?

Hoping someone can clarify me with this one.

Also, I am thinking of implementing the use of `Dapper ORM` on my `Xamarin.Android` Project with respect to `SQLite Database Engine`. I've already made this approach work with standard `WinForm Apps`. So it is also possible with `Xamarin.Android`?

Comment: In my own performance tests, sqlite-net-pcl was way faster than System.Data.SQLite.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the name says, `sqlite-net-pcl` is for use in PCL (Portable class library).

When using `Xamarin` you want to share code between platforms and the best way to do it is via PCL.

Using `sqlite-net-pcl` o can have you database login in PCL and with that you get cross platform database access.

Regarding the `Dapper ORM`, it seems you can use it in `Xamarin.Android` more info [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/17527/dapper-dot-net-with-xamarin) and [here](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net/issues/547).

Comment: by `PCL` you mean the use of `Xamarin.Forms` right ?. but what if, let's say the project is focused on `Xamarin.Android` ?. sorry for asking strange questions.

interesting enough, is there any difference with `sqlite-net-pcl` and `System.Data.SQLite` packages ?. like, the way one will use them, the syntax, and the database file. is it just the same ?

Comment: PCL does't mean the use of Xamarin Forms. You can have PCL in your Android Project. It would make sense if you later on need to add the iOS application. If you don't want to use PCL, i would recomend to use the sqlite-net https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net

Comment: this is interesting. maybe i'll check in more to sqlite-net-pcl and explore while i'm at it. thank you :)